# axios SharePoint error in IE 11 but not Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

When I use axios with SharePoint, it successfully works in Chrome but not in IE 11.  The error is **'Promise' is undefined**.  Using the polyfill does not work either.  Any ideas? Code below:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
"/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('staffing')/items";
  axios.get(endPointUrl).then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
  })
}
```

These are the libraries I use

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://afhq.egovservices.net/sites/Isaac/Webparts/staffing/staffing.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like an axios bug: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1694

Comment: Do you know how I can get just a link reference to a library? The bug seems to point to a npm package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you should reference "auto" version of es6-polyfill:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
```